# Access not parsing entire SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a feeling there must be a stupid mistake here that I can't see, but I've been staring at it so long that I'm at a loss. I'm generating an SQL statement via VBA, and I keep getting a weird error. The SQL comes out looking like this:

```
SELECT c.Junction_ID AS [ID], c.[First_Name] AS [First Name], c.[Last_Name] AS [Last Name], 
  c.Location, c.Start_Date AS [Start Date], c.End_Date AS [End Date], 
  s.Helpful_Scale AS [Helpfulness], s.Memory_Scale AS [Memory] 
FROM nka_ClassList_Unique c 
INNER JOIN nka_Supplemental s ON c.Junction_ID = s.Junction_ID 
INNER JOIN nka_ClassList_Unique_Mgrs m ON m.Location = c.Location 
  AND ((c.Start_Date BETWEEN m.StartDate AND m.EndDate) 
    OR (c.End_Date BETWEEN m.StartDate AND m.EndDate) 
    OR (m.StartDate BETWEEN c.Start_Date AND c.End_Date) 
    OR (m.EndDate BETWEEN c.Start_Date AND c.End_Date)) 
WHERE ((c.Management = False) AND (c.Dist_Manager = False) 
  AND (m.Junction_ID = 129880) AND (c.Location = "DEC"))
```

Access raises the following error (I've formatted it to fit on the screen):

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
`c.Junction_ID = s.Junction_ID INNER JOIN nka_Sprint1_ClassList_Unique_Mgrs m 
  ON m.Location = c.Locatio'.
```

What would cause Access to stop parsing this query partway through a field name? It doesn't have anything to do with stopping after a certain number of characters. Even if I change the length of the `SELECT` statement of the table aliases, it always stops at `c.Locatio`.

Any thoughts on why it would be doing this? There must be something dumb I'm overlooking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSAccess is a little bit picky when joining more than two tables. It requires parenthesis between joins,

```
SELECT c.junction_id   AS [ID], 
       c.[first_name]  AS [First Name], 
       c.[last_name]   AS [Last Name], 
       c.location, 
       c.start_date    AS [Start Date], 
       c.end_date      AS [End Date], 
       s.helpful_scale AS [Helpfulness], 
       s.memory_scale  AS [Memory] 
FROM   ((nka_classlist_unique c 
       INNER JOIN nka_supplemental s 
               ON c.junction_id = s.junction_id)  // <<== observe the parenthesis
       INNER JOIN nka_classlist_unique_mgrs m 
               ON m.location = c.location 
                  AND ( ( c.start_date BETWEEN m.startdate AND m.enddate ) 
                         OR ( c.end_date BETWEEN m.startdate AND m.enddate ) 
                         OR ( m.startdate BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date ) 
                         OR ( m.enddate BETWEEN c.start_date AND c.end_date ) ) )
WHERE  ( ( c.management = false ) 
         AND ( c.dist_manager = false ) 
         AND ( m.junction_id = 129880 ) 
         AND ( c.location = "dec" ) )
```

Comment: Ahh... that did the trick. Thanks, this was driving me crazy!